# Petl to export data to a mongodb collection in docker

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, petl

I want to ingest data from a `csv` file into a `mongodb` collection ruining in a `docker` container by using just python. Do you have any idea how can I do so?

Comment: You could also try mongoimport.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from http import client
import pandas as pd  
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/',username="yourusername", password="yourpassword")

db = client['mydb']
data = pd.read_csv('formated_csv.csv')
data=data.to_dict(orient="records")
db.mycollection.insert_many(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).